# Silverlight: Why doesn't this binding expression work?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having difficulty with a binding expression in Silverlight 3 for the Windows Phone 7.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">    
    <controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding SectionViewModels}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!-- this is the troublesome binding (for Visibility) -->
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource disabledText}" 
                           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.NoStoryContent}">
                    Do you have a network connection?
                </TextBlock>
                <!-- ... -->
```

The style, in **app.xaml**:

```
<Style x:Key="disabledText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
</Style>
```

Code behind:

```
public Visibility NoStoryContent
{
    get
    {
        // trivial return value for debugging
        // no breakpoint here is hit
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}

public Sections()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I suspect I have a mistake in the binding expression, but I'm not sure where.

**Update**: I don't see any error messages in the debug output.

**Update 2**: When I say 'doesn't work', I mean 'the control is always visible even though I'm trying to make it be collapsed, and the property that its Visibility is binding to is never accessed.'

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Have you checked the output window for any error messages?

Comment: The problem is with the `Visibility` binding, not the `StaticResource` style.

Comment: Try a `DebugConverter` to find out what is wrong. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/debugwpfdatabinding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try just {Binding NoStoryContent}

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [iNotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your class

Comment: Does that really prevent it from binding even once?

Comment: And, I actually have. Firing the event for that property changing doesn't do anything.